# How to get access to the input of textbox at aspx web page?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am a starter for asp .net. On my webpage, there are a few textboxes and a submit botton. Is there a easy way to get access the data and use it to built an object ? The textboxes has there names and ids, there should be a way to get access them by names and ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

this is normal html control

```
<input type="text" class="text-box" id=xxx />
```

if you want to access it in your codebehind file you need to add `runat=server` attribute to this

```
<asp:textbox>
```

Other one is server side control asp.net control not html control

I think its better you read out basic of asp.net before stating programming because this is very basic question you should know about

**prev**

step 1:
make use of asp.net Textbox

```
<asp:Textbox id="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
```

Step 2:
for asp.net you just need to write in you codebehind file

```
object.proertyname = texboxid.Text;
```

Read more : [TextBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx)

Comment: I was using <input type="text" class="text-box" id=xxx /> and it is not working. what is the difference between <input type=text> and <asp:textbox>?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new to web development.